# How to resolve the syntax error of python?

Tags: python

I'm getting error as:

```
File "main.py", line 7
     rem = x % 10
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Write a Python program to implement your own `myfilter()` function which works exactly like Python's built-in function `filter()`:

```
def armstrong(x):
  sum =0
  temp = armstrong
  x =154
  while(x > 0):
    {
      rem = x % 10
      sum == sum + rem + rem + rem      
      x = x/10
    }
    if(temp == sum ):
      {
        print("arm")
      }
      elif
      {
        print ("not arm")
      }

arm=filter(armstrong,154)
print(arm)
```

Comment: Try removing the braces.

Comment: That's simply not Python. You really need to brush up on the basics: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1):

Python code does not utilise braces "{" and "}" to denote the beginning and ending of loops and conditions, Python uses ":" and indentation instead.

Hence your code looks like this:

```
def armstrong(x):

  sum =0
  temp=armstrong
  x =154

  while(x > 0):
    rem = x % 10
    sum == sum + rem + rem + rem      
    x = x/10

    if(temp == sum):
        print("arm")
    elif:
        print("not arm")

arm=filter(armstrong,154)
print(arm)
```

However, the code block appears to be incorrect, as it an else if.

```
elif:
    print("not arm")
```

If your intention was else, it should be as per follows:

```
else:
    print("not arm")
```

Which makes your complete code as per belows:

```
def armstrong(x):

  sum =0
  temp=armstrong
  x =154

  while(x > 0):
    rem = x % 10
    sum == sum + rem + rem + rem      
    x = x/10

    if(temp == sum):
        print("arm")
    else:
        print("not arm")

arm=filter(armstrong,154)
print(arm)
```